# str giving only one element as output but object fix the problem

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, object

I have to write a python code, there are a function and it receive a tuple as parameter where all the elements of tuple are numpy array. The output of that code will give me unique hobbies from this tuple. But if I use dtype = str to make a new array it only takes the first letter of the element but if I use dtype = object then it fixes the problem

```
def analyzeHobbies(* participants): #(* arguments) is used for variable number of parameters
  length = len(participants)
  total = 0
  for i in range(length):
    total = total+ len(participants[i])
  new = np.zeros (total, dtype = object)
  count = 0
  for j in range(length):
    for k in range(len(participants[j])):
      
      new[count] = participants[j][k]
      count += 1
  unique1 = np.zeros (total, dtype = object)
  unique1[0] = new[0]
  for h in range(1,total):
    if new[h] not in unique1:
      unique1[h] = new[h]
    else:
         unique1[h] = "0"

  count = 0
  for l in range(len(unique1)):
   if unique1[l]!= "0":
    count = count+1
  
  final = np.zeros (count, dtype = object)
  index = 0 
  for m in range(len(unique1)):
    if unique1[m] != "0":
      final[index] = unique1[m] 
      index = index+1

  print(f"""Unique Activities in the Town:
{final}""") 
  print("Statistics:")
  for n in range(count):
    count1 = 0  
    for o in range(len(new)):
      if final[n] == new[o]:
        count1 = count1+1
    print(f"{count1}participant(s) like(s){final[n]} ")

print("///  Task 04: Get Those Hobbies  ///")
participant_1 = np.array( ["Hiking", "Reading", "Photography", "Cooking"])
participant_2 = np.array( ["Reading", "Hiking", "Painting"])
participant_3 = np.array( ["Hiking", "Cooking", "Photography"])
print(f'Task 4:')
analyzeHobbies(participant_1, participant_2, participant_3) #
```

This should print

```
Unique Activities in the Town:
['Photography', 'Painting', 'Cooking', 'Reading', 'Hiking']

Statistics:
2 participant(s) like(s) Photography.
1 participant(s) like(s) Painting.
2 participant(s) like(s) Cooking.
2 participant(s) like(s) Reading.
3 participant(s) like(s) Hiking.
```

This is how I have done it. Is it possible to do this problem without using object?

Comment: You probably should be using pandas rather than numpy if your array contains strings.

Comment: Not in numpy.  In numpy, `dtype=str` means an array with one letter per element.  Strings in numpy are handles as `dtype=object`.  Why do you have an issue with this?  By the way, it would be much smarter to handle this using a Python set instead of numpy.

Comment: @TimRoberts I am not sure but my teacher may not approve my assignment if I use dtype = object

Comment: Based on what?  It is simply a fact that strings in a numpy array are stored as `dtype=object`.  Just because `dtype=str` happens to be spelled like `str` does not mean they are the same thing at all.  Numpy has its own type definitions.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks!
I have one other question. If I print an array where dtype = int there are comma after each element. But when I use dtype   = object then there is no comma. How to get comma?

Comment: Use something like `dtype='U20'`, i.e. a string upto 20 characters long.  `object` Python strings can be any length, numpy specific ones have a max length.  For iterative code like this appending strings to a list is likely to be better building an array of strings.  numpy doesn't have special code for strings.

Comment: The default print formats are only for convenience.  If you need a specific format, then you print the items yourself, one by one.

Answer (score 1):

The BEST way to handle this is to skip numpy and use `collections.Counter`, which was created exactly for this situation.

```
import collections
import numpy as np

def analyzeHobbies(* participants):
    unique = collections.Counter()
    for p in participants:
        unique.update(p)

    print("Unique Activities in the Town:")
    print(list(unique.keys())) 
    print("Statistics:")
    for k,v in unique.items():
        print(f"{v} participant(s) like(s) {k}")

print("///  Task 04: Get Those Hobbies  ///")
participant_1 = np.array( ["Hiking", "Reading", "Photography", "Cooking"])
participant_2 = np.array( ["Reading", "Hiking", "Painting"])
participant_3 = np.array( ["Hiking", "Cooking", "Photography"])
print(f'Task 4:')
analyzeHobbies(participant_1, participant_2, participant_3) #
```

Output:

```
///  Task 04: Get Those Hobbies  ///
Task 4:
Unique Activities in the Town:
['Hiking', 'Reading', 'Photography', 'Cooking', 'Painting']
Statistics:
3 participant(s) like(s) Hiking 
2 participant(s) like(s) Reading 
2 participant(s) like(s) Photography 
2 participant(s) like(s) Cooking 
1 participant(s) like(s) Painting
```

Answer (score 0):

Python strings can be any length.  A list of strings contains references to strings that are stored elsewhere in memory:

```
In [879]: alist = ["Hiking", "Reading", "Photography", "Cooking"]; alist
Out[879]: ['Hiking', 'Reading', 'Photography', 'Cooking']
```

Making an array from the list:

```
In [880]: np.array(alist)
Out[880]: array(['Hiking', 'Reading', 'Photography', 'Cooking'],
 dtype='<U11')
```

Here the strings are stored in the array itself.  `numpy` allocates 11 unicode spaces (4 bytes) for each.  It's a different storage that for python lists.

Here `ipython` is displaying the arrays with the `repr` method.  The `str` display of an array omits the commas, `array` and `dtype`:

```
In [881]: print(np.array(alist))
['Hiking' 'Reading' 'Photography' 'Cooking']
```

An object dtype puts references in the array, so it's practically the same as a list:

```
In [882]: np.array(alist, dtype=object)
Out[882]: array(['Hiking', 'Reading', 'Photography', 'Cooking'], 
dtype=object)
```

Creating an array with `str` dtype - note the `dtype`:

```
In [883]: x=np.zeros(4, str)   
In [884]: x
Out[884]: array(['', '', '', ''], dtype='<U1')
```

Putting the list in the 'U1' array results in truncated strings:

```
In [885]: x[:]=alist; x
Out[885]: array(['H', 'R', 'P', 'C'], dtype='<U1')
```

It wouldn't truncate if we specified 'U11' or something bigger.  `object` dtype doesn't truncate either:

```
In [886]: x=np.zeros(4, object); x
Out[886]: array([0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object)
In [887]: x[:]=alist; x
Out[887]: array(['Hiking', 'Reading', 'Photography', 'Cooking'],
 dtype=object)
```

`numpy` doesn't do much of its own string processing, so often sticking with lists is just as good.  `pandas` uses object dtype.

Processing your lists:

```
In [888]: blist = ["Reading", "Hiking", "Painting"]
     ...: clist = ["Hiking", "Cooking", "Photography"]
```

`set` is a pure python way of finding unique elements.  `numpy` unique isn't any better for strings.  `set` uses the same sort of hashing that `dict` does; `np.unique` has to sort the elements, and weed out duplicates.

```
In [890]: set(alist+blist+clist)
Out[890]: {'Cooking', 'Hiking', 'Painting', 'Photography', 'Reading'}
```

I like to use `defaultdict` to collect data like this:

```
In [891]: from collections import defaultdict
In [895]: dd = defaultdict(int)    
In [896]: for l in [alist, blist, clist]:
     ...:     for s in l:
     ...:         dd[s] += 1
     ...:             
In [897]: dd
Out[897]: 
defaultdict(int,
            {'Hiking': 3,
             'Reading': 2,
             'Photography': 2,
             'Cooking': 2,
             'Painting': 1})
```